# escape special characters in `\foreach` loop

Tags: characters, foreach

Is there a way to escape underscores (or other special characters) in variable names in a `\foreach` loop when calling file names? E.g., `\foreach \x in {file\_1, name\_2}{Here is \x.}` gives correct output (ie, 'Here is file_1. Here is file_2'), but `\foreach \x in {file\_1, name\_2}{\input{\x}}` gives an error that file 'file_1' cannot be found.

Comment: use `\string_`  and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` so that underscores print as underscores. Why the `.` in `\input{\x.}` ? looks wrong. If you don't need to print the name just using `_` is enough.

Comment: Thanks, `\string_` works! The `.` is there because it's the end of the sentence; doesn't give me any problems.

Comment: "sentence" inside the argument of `\input` ?

Comment: I think we are misinterpreting each other...I just meant that the `.` is there as a period to end the sentence 'Here is file_1.'.

Comment: That period is fine I was questioning this one: `{\input{\x.}`

Comment: Ah, that one! My mistake, sorry for not reading your question attentively. Indeed, shouldn't be there...edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need not escape `_`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {file_1, file_2}{\input{\x}\par}

\end{document}
```

I have two files called `file_1.tex` and `file_2.tex` containing just

```
I'm file 1
```

(and `2` in the second file).

[image]

Note that `\foreach` does its work inside a group, so this may not be the best choice. A different approach uses `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\multiinput}{+O{}m+O{}}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { #1 \input{##1} #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\multiinput[Here: ]{file_1,file_2}[\par]

\end{document}
```

The optional argument can contain code to be executed before and respectively after inputting the file (it's not necessary to have either of them).

[image]